# laravel 8 safety issue for user submitted code in database. How to prevent being hacked?

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I created a website with laravel 8. There are 10 advertisement areas.

Now, I created a system that allow people to join as affiliate member. They will prepare their domains and I will allow them to point DNS to my server. Then they could have their website without purchasing a server.

I created a database table called "affiliate_data" which they could submit their ads code after login through a form using POST method.

```
secret key:
user_domain:
ads code1:
ads code2:
```

They system is working but I have a security concern. In my ads area, my code in the blade is like:

```
if ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] == $data->user_domain){
    {!! $data->ads_code !!}
}
```

My questions are:

1. Is it possible the could get access to my other database data?
2. Any advise to avoid user to edit other website content? They are only allowed to edit the ads area.

Thank you in advanced!

Comment: Massive concerns man, That HTTP_HOST can be easily spoofed. not to mention just dumping user code onto your page.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Any safe way to achieve the similar function? For the HTTP_HOST, I will screen out my own domain before they submit the edit. Can I do something better to handle the code being submit?